# How to cast to a list of a type inaccessible due to protection level?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, nested, private

I have a type in a 3rd party library I can't mark as public but need to iterate through a list of these objects. I can get the object using reflection but this object is of a List. Simply casting it to List did not seem to work.

```
Type pType = typeof(PublicType).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic).First();//gets correct NestedPrivateType, not sure if i can use this to help me cast
object listObj = typeof(PublicType).GetField("_theList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(publicTypeObj);//this gets the list of objects that are of the nested private type
List<object> theList = (List<object>)listObj;//exception, unable to cast
```

I casted the object to List and I expected it to cast properly.

Comment: You can cast `listObj` to IEnumerable and iterate through it with foreach loop.

Comment: @Natan It worked. Question solved. Thanks. If you want to answer the question I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example:

```
object listObj = typeof(PublicType).GetField("_theList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(publicTypeObj);
```

To enumerate through *listObj* you can cast it to IEnumerable and use it with foreach loop:

```
IEnumerable theEnumerable = (IEnumerable)listObj;
foreach (var item in theEnumerable) { ... }
```

Comment: do you know if there are ways to remove items from IEnumerable in this case?

Comment: @Cheyenne If private type is *List<T>*, you can cast your field to **IList** instead *IEnumerable*. Then you have available `void Remove(object? value)` and `void RemoveAt(int index)` methods.